# Ns for the earnings cohorts

Tags: collegescorecard

The "most recent cohorts" has earnings for cohorts at 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 years after entry.  Questions:

1. The documentation appears to indicate that these are earnings for different cohorts with different entry years, not earnings at different points in time for the same cohort.  Is that correct?
2. According to the data dictionary, "count_ed" variable is "count of students in the earnings cohort."  But since there are 6 earnings cohorts, which cohort is it for?
3. The "count_ed" from the raw data file merged_2005_PP appears to match the count_ed in the most recent cohort file.  This makes it seem like the count_ed in the most recent cohorts data is for the cohort entering in 2005, and Ns for other cohorts might be obtained by looking in later raw data files.  However, the count_ed field is NULL in all the merged_YYYY_PP where YYYY>2005.  Is there another way to get cohort sizes for the earnings data for any cohort other than the 10 year?

Answer (score 2):

The "data cohort map" provides the information on which variable represents what cohort and measurement period for each variable in each raw data file (available by clicking download all data) and featured downloads file.  For example the count_ed variable in the Merged_2005 file describes the award year (AY) 2005, 2006 pooled cohort.

The variable, count_wne_p10  represents the N for md_earn_wne_p10 (median earnings of those working and not enrolled in school during the measurement period for earnings measured 10 years after initial enrollment). In the merged_2011 data file this represents AY2001, 2002 pooled cohort measured in calendar year (CY)2011,2012 for both variables (the count and the earnings).  In that same raw data file, count_wne_p6  represents the N for md_earn_wne_p6 (AY2005, 2006 pooled cohort measured in CY2011,2012).

Please note that count_ed goes all the way back to AY1997, 1998 pooled cohort in the Merged1997 file.